# Destroye qthread in pyqt5 at dialog windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread

I am trying to learn python3 and qt5 so in order i am writing a simple application. In my application i have 3 class `MainWindowApp,Ui_Dialog,CopyDebugThread`.

In MainWindowApp i have 2 textedit and one pushbutton.first textedit get address file nd second one get destination folder to save copy of the file.When i click on the pushbutton it's called `openCopyDialog` method in `MainWindowApp` class:

`self.pushButton_copy.clicked.connect(self.openCopyDialog)`

```
def openCopyDialog(self):
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog(self.source_debug_file,self.dest_folder)
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    ui.setSizeFiles()
    ui.runCopyThread()
    Dialog.show()
    Dialog.exec_()
```

This method shows `Ui_Dialog` class and `runCopyThread()` method inside this class.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from CopyDebugThread import *
import os
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def __init__(self,sou_d, dest,):
        self.source_debug_path = sou_d
        self.des_path = dest

def runCopyThread(self):
    debug_thread = CopyDebugThread(self.source_debug_path,self.path_d)
    debug_thread.start()
    debug_thread.change_value.connect(self.setProgressBarVal)


def setProgressBarVal(self, val):
    self.pb_debug.setValue(val)
```

This method `runCopyThread` make an object from `CopyDebugThread` class. CopyDebugThread class is a `Qthread` class.

`setProgressBarVal` method is for get result of percentage of mount of transferred of the file and to show on progressbar.

This is all the code inside `CopyDebugThread` class:
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import os

```
class CopyDebugThread(QThread):
    change_value = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, src_d, dest_d, parent= None ):
        super(CopyDebugThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.src_debug = src_d
        self.dest_debug = dest_d

    def run(self):
        print("run started",self.src_debug +" "+self.dest_debug)
        self.copyfileobj( src= self.src_debug, dst=self.dest_debug, callback_progress=self.progress, callback_copydone=self.copydone )

    def progress(self, fsrc, fdst, copied):
        size_src = os.stat( fsrc.name ).st_size
        size_dst = os.stat( fdst.name ).st_size
        float_src = float( size_src )
        float_dst = float( size_dst )
        percentage = int(float_dst/float_src*100)
        try:
            self.change_value.emit(percentage)
        except:
            pass   

    def copydone(self, fsrc, fdst, copied): 
       self.change_value.emit(100)
       self.quit()    
    #    self.close()


    def copyfileobj(self, src, dst, callback_progress, callback_copydone, length=8*1024):
        print("copyfileobj started")
        c = 0
        c_max = 50
        with open(src, 'r', encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as fsrc:
            with open(dst+"/test.ts", 'w') as fdst:
                copied = 0
                while True:
                   buf = fsrc.read(length)
                   if not buf:
                       break
                   fdst.write(buf)     
                   copied += len(buf)
                   c += 1
                   if c == c_max:
                       callback_progress(fsrc=fsrc, fdst=fdst, copied=copied)
                       c = 0
                callback_copydone(fsrc=fsrc, fdst=fdst, copied=copied)
```

But when i run application and do copy file i got this error and `run` method is never called because `print` method is not printed anything in my terminal :

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
Aborted (core dumped)
```

What is my mistake ?

Comment: change `debug_thread` to `self.debug_thread`

Comment: like this  `def runCopyThread(self):
        self.debug_thread = CopyDebugThread(self.source_debug_path,self.path_d)
        self.debug_thread.start()
        print("debug_thread started")
        self.debug_thread.change_value.connect(self.setProgressBarVal)` @eyllanesc

Comment: Yes, read the dupe.

Comment: @eyllanesc your way is working . What is happend?

Comment: Read the answer of the duplicate question. In short, a local variable is destroyed after its scope ends, in your case debug_thread is destroyed a moment after starting, so the message says: *QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running*

Comment: Thanks bro .How can i vote you ? @eyllanesc

Comment: Done !  Thanks bro. You safe my time :-)